# Pivot statement randomly produces NULL valued columns (Oracle 12c)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a query that uses a CTE for pivoting. I run the query without pivoting and the results are always the same.

HOWEVER when I pivot this data from rows to columns (about 15 columns MAX), I keep getting inconsistent results. The pivoted columns data (with exception the last column) appear as NULL. Re-running the same query multiple time in SQL Developer SOMETIMES produces the correct query, probably 1/10 times. I even tried removing the ORDER BY clause at the end of the statement with the same results

This is a very strange error and cannot even reliably reproduce it in order to troubleshoot it. Anyone have an idea as to why is this happening, and how to troubleshoot it?

Some points to keep in mind:

- ALL The indexes in the DB were rebuilt recently.
- The query is not running in PARALLEL
- No DML is occurring on the source of data when running the PIVOT query

Below is a sample of the query that I run:

```
WITH T1 AS
  (SELECT COL1,
          COL2,
          COL3,
          COL4,
          COL5
   FROM SOURCE_DATA)
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT *
   FROM T1 PIVOT(MAX(COL2)
                 FOR (COL3) IN (1 AS "1", 2 AS "2", 3 AS "3", 4 AS "4",
                                5 AS "5", 6 AS "6", 7 AS "7", 9 AS "9",
                               12 AS "12", 16 AS "16", 17 AS "17", 19 AS "19", 
                               21 AS "21", 22 AS "22",23 AS "23"))) ORDER BY COL1 ;
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements to recreate your sample data; details of indexes, etc. that may affect the query, the `EXPLAIN PLAN` for your query; the actual output that you get from the query; the expected output from the query; and whether the `EXPLAIN PLAN` has changed. If you cannot replicate the problem then as much information as possible to help us investigate the problem because if we can't replicate it then it is difficult (impossible) to help you.

Comment: It sounds like a bug - possibly related to 17468475, though you haven't shown duplicate terms in your example; might be worth trying the workaround for that. Even if you supply a [mre] that gives this issue for you, it might only be reproducible on your exact version and patch level (and maybe platform). It's probably something to ask Oracle about, if you have a support contract, and they will still look at a problem in 12c...

Comment: Indeed it is difficult to replicate. I will do my best to provide some kind of reproducible environment. Was just curious if anyone else has had issues with Pivoting as I described above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my attempt to create a reproducible example for you guys (it was quite complex and wanted to avoid to disclose any system info) I went ahead and rewrote the CTE query before the `PIVOT`.

No major rewrite, the query logic is the same. Keep in mind that the CTE portion of the original query returned the correct results 100% of the time. The changes to CTE query were getting rid of a `UNION` operation, and rewriting the query using explicit `JOIN` syntax, it was originally a mix of implicit and explicit `JOIN` syntax.

After doing this I confirmed that the results returned by both CTE before the `PIVOT` are identical! As an added bonus, the execution plan now needs 10 steps instead of 16 as previously.

It seems that modifying the CTE query has caused Oracle to be more consistent in the results being returned after `PIVOTING`, and so far I have not run into the issue I was facing. The `PIVOT` now returns the expected results.

Again not exactly sure what caused Oracle to return the correct results after the rewrite without any random `NULL` valued columns. I guess this may be a bug in Oracle 12c, and the CTE Query rewrite (and subsequently different execution plan being generated) just allowed it to return the correct results.